# Recommended way to store and load large JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

I have a list(15000 items) of employee names and ids and list(5000 items) of topic names and ids which I get in the Session Start of my application.

I store these as JSON strings in Session variables and then write them out in the View.

The jQuery autocomplete then uses the JSON strings in the View to show list of employees or topics.

Is this the best way to do it? Somehow having big JSON strings in the View does not seem right.

Should I store the JSON strings in a file and then access it for autocomplete? (I faced issues here in the script running for long)

Comment: For that many items, you should use an Ajax-based autocomplete and only return the results needed. Bloating a page with 20,000 items will kill browser/page performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment as answer: For that many items, you should use an Ajax-based autocomplete and only return the results needed. Bloating a page with 20,000 items will kill browser/page performance and should always be avoided.

As a general *rule of thumb*, if your data is more than 100 records, use Ajax to pull down only matching results.

Comment: Yes, sending _all big_ data to client is bad idea itself. If there is connection to server (and I suppose there is), Ajax-based autocomplete sounds much better.

Comment: Is it Ok to save the json file in App_Data(or other location) and then use the Ajax-based autocomplete?

Comment: Or use a Controller action which takes in the user input and based on it gets the JSON data(which is loaded using AJAX)

Comment: @Ranjith Venkatesh: Use an MVC controller action to match (e.g. based on query string param or even just the `id` param) and return the results. You can return HTML, JSON or even raw text. You can also use WebAPI (and the return type (XML or JSON etc) is decided by the request, but an action will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off using AJAX for this. Using JSON will generally mean you're shipping out a HUGE amount of data to the client, whether that data is useful or not. It's also frowned upon from a security point of view.

Also, I've recently been in a similar situation where AJAX wasn't an option so I decided to experiment with a CSV-JSON parser... That could be an option.

Using the parser meant that my JSON-based code was still valid and usable, yet my data sat in a tidy standalone CSV file and it was processed at the server-side. This significantly reduced the need for JSON's clutter (IDs, sizes, arrays... etc)

I'm not saying this is the best solution, but it worked for me. The data rendered quickly-enough and more importantly, my code was tidier because I didn't have to have that huge bulk of JSON sitting in it, just a few lines to initiate the parser, and I was able to manipulate the data easily because CSV is just that little bit more usable than JSON since it sits in its own tabulated file, in my personal opinion. Also, depending on the nature of your parser, this can have the added benefit of the data being worked-out on the server side, so the huge bulk of the information doesn't directly get shipped out to the client's end, only the data they request...

I'm not an expert on any of this, so please take it with a grain of salt. But the big point is, you shouldn't be using JSON if you have that much data.

Good luck. :)